# Dynamically recalculate Bootstrap Affix's offset() on jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, affix

In my app, I have two jQuery functions:

The first manages a simple slideToggle:

```
$( ".js-support-toggle" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.filter-weight').toggleClass('open');
    $('.filter-weight .dropdown-body').slideToggle();
});
```

And corresponding markup:

```
<section class="dropdown filter-weight">
    <a class="dropdown-title js-filter-toggle">Filter</a>
    <div class="dropdown-body">
        ...
    </div><!-- /dropdown-body-->
</section>
```

The second uses Bootstrap Affix to pin a secondary nav to the top of the page:

```
/* Affixes sidebar nav to top of screen */
$('#scrollspy').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function () {
      return (this.top = $('.header-wrapper').outerHeight(true) + $('.filter-weight').outerHeight(true) + $('.secondary-navigation').outerHeight(true) + $('.filter-weight').outerHeight(true) + 100)
    },
    bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

That offset is determined by gathering the outerHeight() values of every element that comes above the affixed menu—including my slideToggled `.filter-weight` element.

This all works fabulously when that `.filter-weight` element is collapsed. However, if a user toggles it open, and then scrolls down the page, the added height of the toggled element throws off my offset calculation.

How could I rewrite my offset() to dynamically adjust to the variable height of my `.filter-weight` element?